# Get value from LongListSelector item

Tags: c#, xaml

I fill my LongListSelector with this template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,4">
            <Grid Tap="Grid_Tap" x:Uid="{Binding Id}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="150" Height="60" Source="{Binding Logo}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding NazwaSklepu}" FontFamily="/Okazjum;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Open Sans" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="1.0_Images/Vector Smart Object.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding GodzinyOtwarcia}" FontFamily="/Okazjum;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Open Sans Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Foreground="Gray" Margin="25,0,0,0" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="1.0_Images/Vector Smart Object copy 3.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Adres}" FontFamily="/Okazjum;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Open Sans Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="14" Foreground="Gray" Margin="25,0,0,0" x:Name="txtAdres"/>

            </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

As you can see I added Tap event to my grid and Binding id.

How can I obtain this Id in my C# event code?

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary way. I put Id in Tag instead of x:Uid
and used following code:

```
 private void Grid_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = -1;
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        if (int.TryParse((Grid)element.Tag + "", out id)) {
        ... my code 
        }
    }
```